# How to scrape a react table when there are no table tags

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape the table from this [link](http://www.nhl.com/stats/teams?aggregate=0&reportType=game&seasonFrom=20072008&seasonTo=20072008&dateFromSeason&gameType=2&filter=gamesPlayed,gte,1&sort=points,wins&page=0&pageSize=100). There are no table tags on the page so I am trying to access it using the class "rt-table". When I inspect the table in developer tools, I can see the html I need in the elements section (I am using Chrome). However, when I view the source code using requests, this part of the code is now missing. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: `requests` doesn't run Javascript. Use `selenium`.

Comment: How can you tell that this table uses javascript?

Comment: Because you can't see it in the `requests` source, which doesn't execute JS, but it is there in Chrome, after the browser has executed JS in the page.

Comment: By checking the network trace in your browser's dev tools, you can see that the request to http://www.nhl.com/stats/teams?aggregate=... doesn't return the table's content. That means that the table content is loaded via subsequent requests

Comment: Just query the [api](https://api.nhle.com/stats/rest/en/team/summary?isAggregate=false&isGame=true&sort=%5B%7B%22property%22:%22points%22,%22direction%22:%22DESC%22%7D,%7B%22property%22:%22wins%22,%22direction%22:%22DESC%22%7D,%7B%22property%22:%22teamId%22,%22direction%22:%22ASC%22%7D%5D&start=0&limit=100&factCayenneExp=gamesPlayed%3E=1&cayenneExp=gameTypeId=2%20and%20seasonId%3C=20072008%20and%20seasonId%3E=20072008) directly

Answer (score 0):

If you just want those stats you can access the hidden api like this:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = f'https://api.nhle.com/stats/rest/en/team/summary?isAggregate=false&isGame=true&sort=%5B%7B%22property%22:%22points%22,%22direction%22:%22DESC%22%7D,%7B%22property%22:%22wins%22,%22direction%22:%22DESC%22%7D,%7B%22property%22:%22teamId%22,%22direction%22:%22ASC%22%7D%5D&start=0&limit=100&factCayenneExp=gamesPlayed%3E=1&cayenneExp=gameTypeId=2%20and%20seasonId%3C=20072008%20and%20seasonId%3E=20072008'
data = requests.get(url).json()

df = pd.DataFrame(data['data'])
df.to_csv('nj devils data.csv',index=False)
```

To see where I got that URL go to the page you are trying to scrape in your browser, then open Developer Tools - Network - fetch/XHR and hit refresh, you'll see a bunch of network requests happen if you click on them you can explore the data returns in the "preview" tab. This can be recreated like above. This is not always the case, sometimes you need to send certain headers or a payload of information to authenticate a request to an api, but in this case it works quite easily.